# PayPal recurring history convert to specific array format

Tags: php, arrays, paypal

I am getting following history from PayPal recurring profile. Please help me to convert into array. I need to verify "P_TRANSTATE" value to every month. It's really hard to check through following array. Please suggest me or help me to convert array to the following view.

```
[status] => 1
[result] => Array
    (
        [HTTP/1_1_200_OK ... RESULT] => 0
        [RPREF] => RGX51B669592
        [PROFILEID] => 0
        [P_PNREF1] => BL0PEE6F2E98
        [P_TRANSTIME1] => 25-Aug-17  04:46 AM
        [P_RESULT1] => 0
        [P_TENDER1] => C
        [P_AMT1] => 19.99
        [P_TRANSTATE1] => 8
        [P_PNREF2] => BP0PECB1799B
        [P_TRANSTIME2] => 24-Sep-17  04:58 AM
        [P_RESULT2] => 0
        [P_TENDER2] => C
        [P_AMT2] => 19.99
        [P_TRANSTATE2] => 8            
    );
```

Need to following format

```
1] => Array
    (
        [P_PNREF] => BL0PEE6F2E98
        [P_TRANSTIME] => 25-Aug-17  04:46 AM
        [P_RESULT] => 0
        [P_TENDER] => C
        [P_AMT] => 19.99
        [P_TRANSTATE] => 8


[2] => Array
    (
        [P_PNREF] => BP0PECB1799B
        [P_TRANSTIME] => 24-Sep-17  04:58 AM
        [P_RESULT] => 0
        [P_TENDER] => C
        [P_AMT] => 19.99
        [P_TRANSTATE] => 8  );
```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. **Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.**

Comment: I can't understand why gave me down vote for the question ? I think this question is really helpful for developer. And so many developer gave me quick solution. strange.

Comment: Can you see the bold text above? I'll snip out the important part for you: **what has been done so far to solve it.** Your question has no effort at all. You're asking us to do your work without even trying first.

Comment: @Andreas II already checked from my end try my best to do myself. As you see the answer of users, so many help me gave a helpful answer. I think this is not a minus(downvote) question.

Answer (score 2):

If I don't misunderstood your question then this should work for you.

```
<?php
$array =  array
    (
    'HTTP/1_1_200_OK ... RESULT' => 0,
    'RPREF' => 'RGX51B669592',
    'PROFILEID' => 'RP0000000040',
    'P_PNREF1' => 'BQ1PECD4AEB8',
    'P_TRANSTIME1' => '25-Aug-17  04:46 AM',
    'P_RESULT1' => 0,
    'P_TENDER1' => 'C',
    'P_AMT1' => 19.99,
    'P_TRANSTATE1' => 8,
    'P_PNREF2' => 'BT1PFFF8A110',
    'P_TRANSTIME2' => '24-Sep-17  04:58 AM',
    'P_RESULT2' => 0,
    'P_TENDER2' => 'C',
    'P_AMT2' => 19.99,
    'P_TRANSTATE2' => 8,            
);

unset($array['HTTP/1_1_200_OK ... RESULT'],$array['RPREF'],$array['PROFILEID']);
$final_array = [];
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    $index = substr($key, -1);
    $key = substr($key, 0, -1);    
    $final_array[$index][$key] = $value; 
}
print '<pre>';
print_r($final_array);
print '</pre>';
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [P_PNREF] => BQ1PECD4AEB8
            [P_TRANSTIME] => 25-Aug-17  04:46 AM
            [P_RESULT] => 0
            [P_TENDER] => C
            [P_AMT] => 19.99
            [P_TRANSTATE] => 8
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [P_PNREF] => BT1PFFF8A110
            [P_TRANSTIME] => 24-Sep-17  04:58 AM
            [P_RESULT] => 0
            [P_TENDER] => C
            [P_AMT] => 19.99
            [P_TRANSTATE] => 8
        )

)
```

**DEMO:** https://eval.in/978871

*As per the comment of* **Parapluie**: You can use `preg_match()` to get keys/index when it cross the digit after 9 because `substr($key,-1)` or `substr($key,0,-1)` will not work properly then. See below-

```
$re = '/(\D+)(\d+)/';
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
    $index = $matches[2];
    $key = $matches[1];  
    $final_array[$index][$key] = $value; 
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution.

Comment: @VipulJethva glad it works for you. By the way you can accept my answer by clicking on the tick mark :) Best of luck. Happy Coding.

Comment: @AlwaysSunny what will happen when PayPal sends back results above '9'? Won't `substr($key, -1)` only return the final digit? Wouldn't `preg_match` be a wiser method?

Comment: @Parapluie agreed sir, I need to modify then my solution with preg_match to get last part of digits.

Comment: @AlwaysSunny Cool. If you did, it'd be a "voter-upper"!

Comment: @Parapluie **Edited** with `preg_match`, have a look and up-vote it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, assuming $res is the paypal array response.

```
<?php
  function convertArray($arr){
  $temp = array();
  $temp[1] = $arr['result'];
  return $temp;
  }
  print_r(convertArray(r$es));
?>
```

Comment: there is more changes done to the array than that in question.

Comment: It should be display array like, 1] => Array
        (
            [P_PNREF] => BL0PEE6F2E98
            [P_TRANSTIME] => 25-Aug-17  04:46 AM
            [P_RESULT] => 0
            [P_TENDER] => C
            [P_AMT] => 19.99
            [P_TRANSTATE] => 8
        

    [2] => Array
        (
            [P_PNREF] => BP0PECB1799B
            [P_TRANSTIME] => 24-Sep-17  04:58 AM
            [P_RESULT] => 0
            [P_TENDER] => C
            [P_AMT] => 19.99
            [P_TRANSTATE] => 8

Comment: @Andreas, StackOverflow is providing facility to edit a question that's why I edited it. I was thinking to ask more clearly to represent my question that's why I edited my question. I am not happy with downvote of my very good question.

Comment: @VipulJethva You obviously miss the point. It's not about the table or the array. It's the fact that you have not included any code at all in your question. here read about it in Meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341393/what-to-do-with-questions-that-dont-show-any-research-effort

Comment: @Andreas How you know that I didn't add code in my question? There was the problem with showing my array code on it and that's why I edit my question 3 times. that's it

Comment: @VipulJethva But there is still no code in your question. I know it because I can see there is no code in your question. I can also see all your revisions and none of them have code.

Comment: @Andreas You mean to say my question is not well formatted to understand easily or something else?

Comment: @VipulJethva Sigh.. **CODE IS MISSING**. How hard can it be?!

Comment: @Andreas Don't require code to display in my question. I have formatted response which I get from the payment gateway. I just need to convert to a specific format which I require. That's it.